# ¿Como llenar un combobox con la misma información pero en diferentes formularios?

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, combobox, vb, visual

```
Public Sub llenaHs ()

    enunciado = New SqlCommand(" SELECT * from HORAS where id_usu in ('7','19','31','34','38','44','56') order by login asc", conexion)
    adaptador = New SqlDataAdapter(enunciado)
    datos = New DataSet
    adaptador.Fill(datos)
    Me.cbHoras.DataSource = datos.Tables(0)
    Me.cbHoras.DisplayMember = "**"
    Me.cbHoras.ValueMember = "**"

End Sub
```

Tengo un procedimiento en el formulario principal y 1 combobox en cada uno de los 3 formularios que traen diferente información, en todos los formularios, el combobox se llama `cbHoras` necesito saber como hago con el mismo sub llenar los 3 combobox sin tener que poner el nombre del formulario adelante (De esta manera funciona bien) ya que tengo pensado seguir agregando formularios. El Me. esta claro que no funciona ya que en el cuadro principal no tengo ningún combobox. Aguardo sus comentarios.

Comment: Si usas esta funcion en una clase estatica le podrias pasar el nombre del formulario y usarlo en lugar del me... tambien podrias poner todo lo que hace en una clase y devolver el adaptador...

Comment: Tenes que separar tu método que carga los datos de la vista, y solo llamarlo directamente y que te devuelva un array de datos del tipo que necesitas. Si es el mismo array para todos los comboBox podes hacerlo sobre una clase estatica para no volver a instanciarla cada vez que la necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

Crea una clase como la siguiente

```
Public Class ClaseControles

    Private enunciado As SqlCommand

    Public Sub llenaHs(Control As ComboBox)
        Dim enunciado = New SqlCommand(" SELECT * from HORAS where id_usu in ('7','19','31','34','38','44','56') order by login asc", conexion)
        Dim adaptador = New SqlDataAdapter(enunciado)
        Dim datos = New DataSet
        adaptador.Fill(datos)
        Control.DataSource = datos.Tables(0)
        Control.DisplayMember = "**"
        Control.ValueMember = "**"

    End Sub

End Class
```

Para llamarla en tu formulario

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim clasecontroles As New ClaseControles
        clasecontroles.llenaHs(cbHoras)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Excelente, ahi funciona, la conexion la tengo en  conexion.ConnectionString, tengo manera de llamarla desde la clase o tengo que declararla dentro de la clase si o si? Ahora para que funcione, hice esto dentro de la clase.

Dim conexion As New SqlConnection
conexion.ConnectionString = "data source = UNICO; initial catalog = master; Integrated Security = True"
conexion.Open()

Comment: de preferencia realiza lo desde la clase, comúnmente se crea  otra clase para la conexión, te recomiendo  buscar en Internet sobre el Principio SOLID para programación de objetos.

Comment: Excelente Marco. Te agradezco mucho por la ayuda. Saludos